# angular $watch is not work with d3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

look, click the button, $scope.optionis change, but $watch is not work, can`t console.log the option value , why?

I am sorry , it is my mistake , but it still is a problem in I use width d3.js

I use d3.js append a rect into page, and I want to when I click the rect can chagne the option value, but $watch is not work, why?

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.option = '123';
$scope.d3TreeDraw = {
    source : {
        name: 'myTree'
    },
    updata: function(){
        var _self = this;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([90, 60]);

        var nodes = tree.nodes(_self.source).reverse();
        nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 90; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)

        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes)

        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .style('cursor','pointer')
        .on('click', function(d){
            console.log('click'); // can console.log
            $scope.option = '456';
            console.log($scope.option) //is change
              })

        nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr('width',150)
        .attr('height', 30)
        .style('fill', '#000')
    }
}
$scope.d3TreeDraw.updata();

$scope.$watch('option', function(){
    console.log('change:' + $scope.option); // when option is change,can not console.log
})
})
```

Comment: your `ng-click` has `onClick` but in JS code you have `onclick` which aren't the same

Comment: i am sorry , place see my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First You have taken **`myTree.onClick()`** and your function has **`onclick`**

So, the `onClick()` spelling mismatched.

Change button to `<button ng-click="myTree.onclick()">456</button>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click="myTree.onclick()">{{data}}</button>
<br>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.data = '100';
 $scope.myTree = {
        onclick: function() {
            $scope.data = '456';
        }
    }
    $scope.$watch('data', function(){
        console.log($scope.data);
        alert($scope.data);
    })

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is a working **DEMO**.](https://plnkr.co/edit/jDIp7JDnAuuI45429BVV?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

**By checking your edit, I saw that your `scope` assignment is outside of `angular`.**

So, you need to `$apply()` the `$scope`

Change,

**`$scope.option = '456';`**

to,

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.option = '456'
 });
```

The above method, runs the `digest cycle manually`, and apply the changes for the scope.

**Performance:**

If you write `$scope.$apply()` it will run `complete digest cycle`, which will affect the `performance`, so we sent a function into the `$apply` method and only ran the `digest cycle` of specific `scope.

Hence, you can `$watch` the scope whenever you want.

Comment: someone is downvoting without any reason.

Comment: @Martin, please check my answer.

Comment: i am sorry , place see my new answer

Comment: @Martin, replace `$scope.option = '456';` with `$scope.$apply(function () {$scope.option = '456'});`. I will explain why

Comment: @Martin, added the explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have a upper case letter in the function name

change this

```
 <button ng-click="myTree.onClick()">456</button>
```

to this

```
 <button ng-click="myTree.onclick()">456</button>
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.data = '123';
    $scope.$watch('data', function(){
        console.log($scope.data);
    })

    $scope.myTree = {
      
        onclick: function() { 
            $scope.data = '456';
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <button ng-click="myTree.onclick()">456</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i am sorry , place see my new answer